# Keep on getting this error message when trying to run my django server: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-settings, python-django-storages

[image: command line error 2]I'm trying to run my django server but keep on getting this error, [Errno 2] No such file or directory.

I tried using the cd manage.py command but also got this error cd : Cannot find path 'C:\Users\nyaknoiton\Desktop\Django 2\manage.py' because it does not exist. [image: command line error]

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/354577). Instead, format code as a [code block]. The easiest way to do this is to paste the code as text directly into your question, then select it and click the code block button.

Answer (score 1):

You need to cd into **psychology_project** first not **pychology_project**. And then run `python manage.py runserver`

This is where manage.py lives.

Comment: How do i do that please?

Comment: okay i just did cd into psychology_project and it worked but when i run manage.py runserver i get another error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psychology_app'

Comment: I just added another screenshot to show that there is psychology_app and i've let django know that its there.  by including it in installed apps

Comment: Have you intitialised the psychology_app using python manage.py startapp psychology_app? What is in the psychology_app folder?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly (you misspelled it)

```
cd psychology_project
```

Then remember to save your manage.py file to disk (Ctrl-s). Finally

```
python manage.py runserver
```

Comment: still not working